# How to rectify an error message I am observing?

Tags: sas

I am receiving an error message after running the macro  %better_means but I am not sure what options I have to change for the summary statistics to be calculated properly.

```
WARNING: A shortage of memory has caused the quantile computations to terminate prematurely for QMETHOD=OS. Consider using 
             QMETHOD=P2.
    NOTE: The affected statistics will be missing from the corresponding classification levels.
    WARNING: A shortage of memory has caused the quantile computations to terminate prematurely for QMETHOD=OS. Consider using 
             QMETHOD=P2.
    NOTE: The affected statistics will be missing from the corresponding classification levels.
    NOTE: Processing on disk occurred during summarization. Peak disk usage was approximately 9 Mbytes. Adjusting SUMSIZE may improve 
          performance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's caused by the fact that quantile (and percentile) calculations require a lot of memory to run with the default method of calculating them (basically, lining everything up and then finding the 5% mark etc.)  If you have a lot of data, or you have a lot of variables or class variables, you may run into this.  Consider either separating your runs into multiple steps (perhaps do some class variables in one proc means and some in another), or increasing the amount of memory available to SAS.

Comment: How would you increase the memory size?

Comment: `options memsize`, although I believe this is a startup option only (can't be changed during a session).